# what's the difference beetwen jquery and t3jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, typo3-6.2.x

What's the difference between jquery and t3jquery (jQuery direct from Typo3) and why does bootstrap just work with the first one.

Comment: 6.2 Typo 3, the newest t3jquery i could load in the extention manager seems to have the version number of the Cms, and jQuery 3.1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

t3jquery is an extension (not from core!) with the option to build your individual jQuery package (which jQuery-version and which jQuery-modules may be included), so your javascript library for jQuery is minimal to the needs you have. You also can include jQuery with just some clicks from a CDN, which is easier for developers which are not capable to include CDN sources by hand or copy a version of jquery to their server.
Any ready build source other than your local may include all possible jQuery modules.

Individual jQuery library could be faster (less code to load), but also the big include with all modules could be faster as this version might be loaded already from other sides - **IF** you are using CDN for include.

If you use jQuery from your TYPO3 sources (another option) you will be sure, that it is available (no other domain accessed) and it will be an actual version (as far as you update your TYPO3 core), but your visitors need to access files from the BE, which might be restricted for security reason to protect the BE.

If you want to include jQuery the options from above can be realized like this:

**basic include like any other javascript file**

multiple options:
*a copy of jquery you stored somewhere in your filesystem:*

```
page.includeJSLibs {
    jquery = fileadmin/JS/jquery.min.js
}
```

*a copy of jquery you stored somewhere in your site extension:*

```
page.includeJSLibs {
    jquery = EXT:site_abc/Resources/Public/JavaScript/jquery.min.js
}
```

*include of external like a CDN*

```
page.includeJSLibs {
    jquery = //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js
    jquery.external = 1
}
```

**jquery from the TYPO3 core**

```
page.javascriptLibs {
    jQuery = 1
    jQuery.source = local
}
```

**jquery from a CDN**

```
page.javascriptLibs {
    # include jQuery (boolean)
    jQuery = 1
    # Change the version
    # (possible values: latest|1.7.2|…, default: latest)
    # Note: jQuery.source has to be a CDN like "google"
    # when jQuery.version is not "latest"
    jQuery.version = latest
    # Include from local or different CDNs
    # (possible values: local|google|jquery|msn, default: local)
    jQuery.source = jquery
    # Set jQuery into its own scope to avoid conflicts (boolean)
    jQuery.noConflict = 1
    # Change the namespace when noConflict is activated
    # and use jQuery with "TYPO3.###NAMESPACE###(…);"
    # (string, default: jQuery)
    jQuery.noConflict.namespace = ownNamespace
}
```

The extension t3jquery can include the JS lib for you, but preferable you use it to copy an individualized jQuery lib into your filesystem where you can include it yourself.